# Chrome Webstore review delays and unable to cancel pending reviews

Tags: google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store, webstore

The Chrome Webstore has two huge problems that hurt the developer experience.

1. **Updates, even small updates, take multiple days to be reviewed.** I recently pushed a small update to my extension and it took 7 days to be reviewed and approved, that’s ridiculous to be frank. If there was a bug in production, 7 days for a fix to be approved would significantly hurt a developer and/or company. The chrome team needs more reviewing staff and/or adjustments to their review process.
2. **You cannot cancel pending reviews, you can only defer them and wait for them to be reviewed before pushing another update.** I recently pushed an update that I realized had a flaw afterward. Instead of being able to cancel the update I pushed, I have to wait multiple days for it to be approved and then push the corrected update and wait for it to be reviewed again. The inability to cancel pending updates wastes my time AND the Chrome Webstore team’s time.

If you have experienced these problems and/or agree with my points, it would benefit the web developer community to leave the Chrome Webstore team feedback via this link: https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/survey_transactional!